# strcmp/char* conversion not works as expected

Tags: c++, arduino

I have written an MQTT client callback function and my code never calls the `handleEmptyJsonMessage()`. It seems to me that (`char*`) conversion or the `strcmp` function is not works as I expect.

How can I compare `byte *payload` to a string/`char[]`?

```
void mqttCallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
    if (strcmp((char*)payload, "{}") == 0) {
      handleEmptyJsonMessage();
    } else {
      Serial.println("skip message");
    }
}
```

Comment: `payload` likely does not point to a _string_.  Post calling code, an [mcve] and review your code's for a missing _null character_.

Comment: payload likely does not point to a string.  -> it comes from PubSubClient (mqtt client library for arduino), in other case it worked for me (JsonObject &inputObject = jsonBuffer.parseObject(payload))

Comment: you can see the source code here: https://github.com/kisdaniel/HomeDashboardGarageDoorOpener/blob/compare-bug/HomeDashboardGarageDoorOpener.ino at line 385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your `payload`-buffer is not a string in the sense that it is terminated by a `\0`-character.

Better use

```
    strncmp((char*)payload, "{}",length) == 0)
```

Note that the correct treatment of the contents of `payload` depends on semantics not described in your question. E.g. it needs to be guaranteed that `length` does not exceed the `payload`-buffer; if `payload` is a string longer than `"{}"`, please decide if you want to treat this as equal or not.

Anyway, the `strxxx`-functions require a string terminated with `\0`; otherwise it is very likely that you yield undefined behaviour.

Comment: ...or `memcmp()`